# java program to access HiveMetastore from Windows AD using ssltrustore/knox

Tags: hive, hadoop2, thrift, knox-gateway

My requirement is to connect a java program for accessing hive metastore from windows AD to Hiveserver2/thrift 
installed on linux machine using sslTrustStore .jks file and trustStorePassword.
It look like cluster have knox enabled.
I am able to connect using JDBC URL "jdbc:hive2: " and run sql query.
Note - Keytab is not accessible to us.
We don't have metastore connection details to connect using JDBC.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question given the lack of information, it would be good if you can provide more info. When you say you are able to connect using JDBC are you going through Knox ? if the cluster has Knox configured properly then you (clients accessing Knox) do not need to use Keytab. You can use Knox rest api to access metastore info https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-1-0-0/user-guide.html#WebHCat

Comment: Yes, I can connect JDBC using URI like "jdbc:hive2:<host:port;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=file.jks;trustStorePassword=pswd;transportMode=http;httpPath=gateway/default/hive> "

Comment: @SandeepMore On given link I can see program under section Client JDBC Example which only execute simple sql query. I need a sample program that extend to get metastore information like getting all databases getting all schema.. field and datatypes.

Comment: Well, you can try changing the SQL query, SHOW DATABASES/SCHEMAS should do.